# Selecting N+1th highest row in Oracle if it exists or else return Nth highest

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

In a table with M Columns, I  want the row that contains the (n+1)th highest value in Column J given the nth highest value of Column J. If there is no (n+1)th highest value of Column J, then the query should return the row containing the nth highest value in Column J. 
Is it possible that I can do this using a single query using rownum or rank() ?

For Example In the below table if I want to run the query on Column B,

```
A     B     C
=============
1     3     4     -> ROW1
8     4     5     -> ROW2
9     5     2     -> ROW3
0     0     1     -> ROW4
```

> QUERY(ROW1) => returns ROW4 since ROW4 has the next highest value for
>   Col B which is 0 QUERY(ROW2) => returns ROW1 since ROW1 has the next
>   highest value for Col B which is 3
>
> But if I run QUERY(ROW4), it should return ROW4 itself since there is
>   no other lower value for Col B.

By next highest I mean the N+1th highest value when sorted in Descending order. SO there is no next highest value for the lowest value.

Is it possible that I can do this using a single query?

Comment: Ok, maybe it's my feeble mind, but i have re-read your question several times and I STILL HAVE *no idea* what the goal is.  You say "QUERY(ROW1) => returns ROW4 since ROW4 has the next highest value for Col B which is 0".  But, Col B, ROW1 is 3, the next highest value is 4, which is in ROW2, and then 5 which is in ROW3.  ROW4 has 0, which is *less* than 3.  So, you can see my confusion here.  Please provide a better example of inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. By next highest I mean the N+1th highest value when sorted in Descending order. So there is no next highest value for the lowest value. Just added the edit.

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything for me, actually. You want the nth highest value of column J, but there is no column J, only A, B and C. Then you query ROW1 to get ROW4??? That makes no sense to me at all. Sorry.

Comment: When you sort the col B in descending order you have the following order:

ROW3
ROW2
ROW1
ROW4

So if my input is row1, the query should return row4.
If my input is row2, the query should return row1
But if my output is row4, then the output should be row4 itself.
Since there's no further lower value for Col B

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
WITH subquery AS (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnJ DESC) AS row_id
  FROM   table_name
)
SELECT *
FROM   subquery
WHERE  row_id = CASE WHEN :required_rank = (SELECT MAX(row_id) FROM subquery)
                     THEN :required_rank
                     ELSE :required_rank + 1 END;
```

Comment: WITH subquery AS (select rownum as row_id, A, B, C from (select * from test_table order by C)) SELECT * FROM   subquery WHERE  row_id = CASE WHEN :rank = (SELECT MAX(row_id) FROM subquery) THEN :rank ELSE :rank + 1 END;

This query works for the above table

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table
WHERE B IN (SELECT nvl(max(B), ?) FROM some_table WHERE B < ?)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed855/4) example.